# Amazon Neptune MemoryLimitExceeded on a small dataset with cycles

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am querying on a small database ~10k edges and ~2k vertices

```
g.V("{}").repeat(outE().inV()).until(hasId(eq("{}")))
```

Though the query is somewhat brute force, with such a small dataset I would have expected it to fetch very quickly. in reality it results in

```
Query cannot be completed due to memory limitations
```

Is this expected on such a small dataset?

Comment: Does the data set contain cycles? If so you may want to add a `simplePath()` to your `repeat`. The query could well be running out of memory because it is essentially in an infinite loop.

Comment: You could actually cause this with a 2 node, 2 edge graph, if it has cycles and the query is not written in a way to defend against that. So it's not really going to be the size of the graph, more the presence of cycles that is most likely causing this.

Comment: I will add a concrete example in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles in graphs are common, and by no means something that should always be considered an error. Consider the case where person A is friends with person B, and person B is friends with person A.

We might model that as:

```
(A)-FRIEND->(B)-FRIEND->(A)
```

This is a perfectly reasonable design as we may want to allow for the case where person A claims to be a friend of person B, but person B has not yet acknowledged they are indeed friends with person A. So, we have an edge in each direction. However, we now have a cycle in our data.

The sample graph described above, can be created using:

```java
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addE('FRIEND').from('a').to('b').
  addE('FRIEND').from('b').to('a')
```

Using your case as an example, we might be tempted to write the query:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('A').repeat(out()).until(hasId('X'))
```

However, given the cycles in the graph, that is essentially an infinite loop as we will constantly visit A,B,A,B etc. and never find a vertex with the ID of 'X'.

We can observe that "infinite loop" using a `timeLimit` step to interrupt the query to stop it running away completely.

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').repeat(timeLimit(1).out()).until(hasId('X')).emit()
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
```

As can be seen, the query is stuck in a tight loop. `V[0]` is A and `V[1]` is B. The query only ends due to the time limit.

So, we need to code our query to handle these cases. The two most common ways to do this are to use either `simplePath` or `cyclicPath` depending upon whether you want to capture the cycle or just filter out any results that include cycles.

```java
// No results as simplePath stops the traversal as soon as a cycle is found
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId('X')).path().by(label)

// We get a result as we stop after finding the cycle but include it in the results
g.V().hasLabel('A').repeat(out()).until(hasId('X').or().cyclicPath()).path().by(label)

==>[A,B,A]
```