# Graph Database Design to Avoid Loops

Tags: database-design, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am designing a system that computes best shipping route for commercial containers.
as such the path a container *typically* takes is: 
**pickup** -> **port of load** -> **port of destination** -> **delivery**

I have composed a list of known locations from which a pickup/delivery can take place (such as cities) and a list of ports as well as the connections between those.

a sample of the data can be seen here
[image]

When looking for a route between **Austin -> Frankfurt** the graph should return only this path:

1. Austin -> Florida -> Port of Florida -> Port of Hamburg -> Frankfurt

Austin -> NYC -> Port of NYC -> Port of London -> Port of Hamburg ->Frankfurt is ruled out because it has two international steps

the graph also returns round trips (which it should not return) for example
Austin -> Florida -> Port of Florida -> Port of Hamburg -> Berlin -> Port of Hamburg -> Frankfurt

thus far I have composed the following gremlin query

```
g.V(*from_vertices)
    .repeat(
        outE()
        .has("ff_id", within(ff_id, "ANY"))
        .has("quote_methods", containing(quote_method.value))
        .has("valid_to", gte(current_date))
        .has("valid_from", lte(current_date))
        .in_v()
    )
    .until(hasId(within(*to_vertices)))
    .path()
    .as_("p")
    .map(unfold().coalesce(values("international_stops"), constant(0)).sum_())
    .as_("international_stops")
    .filter_(select("international_stops").is_(lte(1)))
    .select("p")
    .map(unfold().coalesce(values("pricing_document_ids"), constant("")).fold())
    .to_list()
```

I face two issues:

1. loops in the graph, the graph contains many loops, in addition to immediate ones it also contains round trips that take an arbitrary amount of edges
2. Due to memory and performance limitations I am **unable to get all paths and then filter the ones containing loops**

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: Please note that the [tag:graphdb] tag (in contrast to the [tag:graph-databases] tag) is for a specific product, which, I suppose, you are not using, right?

Comment: Please also see the answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337850/aws-neptune-memorylimitexceededexception-on-a-small-dataset/74348078#74348078

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're missing here is the `simplePath()` step [1][2].  This will ignore cycles found by the `repeat()` step.

Ex:

```
g.V(<id>).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(<target-id>)).path()
```

[1] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#simplepath-step

[2] https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#sp

Answer (score 0):

I may recommend **GraphScope** for your graph query needs due to its impressive performance and scalability.

In your cases,

1. GraphScope provide a `PathExpand()` operator, and you can query a simple_path (with no loops) simply by:

```
g.V().out("1..5").with('PATH_OPT', 'SIMPLE')
```

More details and examples can be found in the [official doc](https://graphscope.io/docs/interactive_engine/tinkerpop/supported_gremlin_steps#pathexpand).

2. GraphScope is designed to be efficient and scalable. It outperforms  other systems such as mongoDB and Neo4j (Communication Version) by orders of magnitude.

Beside, GAIA-IR, the interactive graph query engine in GraphScope, provides a unified intermediate representation layer, making it easily to incorporate various graph query languages. Currently, GAIA-IR already supports the most popular graph query languages including Gremlin and Cypher.

You could refer to this [article](https://blog.graphscope.io/gaia-ir-graph-interactive-query-engine-in-graphscope-340993f4637c) to learn the design of GAIA-IR and how it can be deployed and used.

Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.